# How to ask someone in a phone call to pass the phone to someone else?

Tags: idioms

Example in English:

You are on the phone with John, and you know that Mary is in a room with him, you may say
"Can you put on Mary, please?".

Is there an idiom for this request in Japanese?

Comment: （電話）マリーに代わってもらえる？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually say

> メアリーにかわってくれますか。
>   Can you put Mary on the phone?